# Magento 1.9 change customize the search result based on custom attribute value

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, custom-attributes

I have a magento 1.9 and would like to customize the search result in such way the it will show result based on a custom attribute I have in the system. we are selling fabrics and each fabric has a custom attribute called "Pattern" ( we have more custom attributes) . this custom attribute has the values "Solid,Paisley,Patchwork" . I would like to modify search result to show "Solid" first when people search .

I appreciate your comment .

Comment: Please search with third party extension.

Comment: Thanks for the advise .

Comment: Im looking at amasty Search pro now hope it can do the job.

However , I also  wanted to know if it is possible for magento 1 search result to show the result in different order. right now it show the last address products , Can I force magento to show me Mix ordered products in the results ?

thanks